# As of today Jan-2014. How much drive space does the following coins blockchain data take?

Tags: blockchain, altcoin, storage-footprint

As of today 2014-January-05.

How much drive space does each of these coins take after downloading the complete blockchain?

1. Bitcoin
2. Litecoin
3. PPCoin
4. Florincoin
5. Philosopher Stone
6. Norbits
7. Anonymous Coin

Or better yet, is there a website that shows all this data with these altcoins.

Comment: For Litecoin, it's 2.0GiB as of 2014-jan-05 (just the blocks folder).

Comment: -1 This is not a useful question, it requires an undue amount of work to answer completely, and encourages a multitude of partial answers.

Answer (score 1):

6 january 2014
Bitcoin blockchain: 14.9 GB (the size of the /data/blocks folder)